# Google Site Verification Failure - HTML File Upload method

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-search-console

I have an Express/NodeJS app running on Google App Engine, for which I have the URL in the format of:
project-name.appspot.com, where project-name: My google project name

Now, for site verification, I am using HTML File Upload method.

I am serving the html verification file provided by google as follows:

```js
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, path_to_html_file))
```

Now, when I enter the url: https://project-name.appspot.com/, I can view the file.
Also, the file has the same name as provided by Google.

However, when I click Verify in Webmaster, it still fails with error message "File not Found"

Can anyone point what I might be doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Isn't Google trying to go to the url: `https://project-name.appspot.com/xxxxxxxx.html`?

Comment: Google instruction is to serve the html file at https://project-name.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serve this file from the `/xxxxx.html` url, not the root url.
In other words, it needs to be accessed from `https://project-name.appspot.com/xxxxxxxx.html`

Think about it...  This file must stay up for as long as you want to be verified, so it doesn't make sense to be shown at the root url.

Also, make sure there are no redirects in serving this file.

Comment: Yes. Sounds reasonable. I'll try that out and get back.

Comment: Worked. Thanks! Only thing pending now is Oauth Consent Screen verification. I hope the HTML file upload verification is good enough. Because I dont think it is possible to add Google TXT records to an appspot URL

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in the public folder, for an Express app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).